# Powershell script to display a list of users and respective permissions of a shared mailbox

Tags: powershell, email

I thought I'd post this here just in case I'm barking up the wrong tree. I'm looking to put together a Powershell script that can list all of the members of a shared mailbox and their respective permissions (Limited to "UserName", "Name", "Mailbox", "Full Access", "Send As",     "SOBO"). My plan is for the script to ask for an email address and output to look something like this:

```
User      Name            Mailbox         Full Access     Send As     SOBO      Success
----      ----            -------         -----------     -------     -----     --------

ACB123    Smith, James    Examplebox      Yes             Yes          No       Success
ABC213    Smith, Pete     Examplebox      Yes             No           Yes      Success
```

I was surprised when I couldn't find anything online that is even similar to this.

My script, so far, grabs a list of users that have Full Access (well, it's supposed to, it seems to grab the lesser permissions too, but this actually serves my purpose). The script then strips the collected info down to usernames, then runs a `for each` to gather information to complete the table above. It runs an AD query for the display names as running `Get-ADPermission` is not an option.
I haven't got as far as to do the Send As and SoBo parts of the table because I can't get the table to be bigger than 4 columns before it turns into a list, instead of a table. I know there's the `Format-Table` command but I can't seem to integrate it into my current pscustomobject setup - which is currently set up to split successful queries from failed ones.

This is what I have so far, it's pretty dirty, but this is just my best guess to how something like this should work:

```
import-moduleactivedirectory
Install-ModuleExchangeOnlineManagement
Connect-ExchangeOnline-ShowBanner:$false
Clear-Host
$ErrorActionPreference='Stop'
$status=[System.Collections.Generic.List[pscustomobject]]::new()

$Entered_email=$Entered_email.trim()
$Collect_SendAs=Get-Mailbox$Entered_email-resultsizeunlimited|Get-RecipientPermission|where {($_.trustee -ne"NT AUTHORITY\SELF")} |where {($_.trustee -match"@")} |selectTrustee
$Collect_users=Get-Mailbox-Identity$Entered_email-ResultSize:Unlimited|Get-MailboxPermission|?{($_.IsInherited -eq$False) -and-not ($_.User -match"NT AUTHORITY")} #|select -ExpandProperty user
$status=foreach($Aliasin$Collect_users)

{
    try
    {
        $User= ($Alias.User.Split("@")[0])
        $Access=$Alias.AccessRights
        $User_name=Get-ADUser-identity$User-propertiesDisplayName|select-expandpropertyDisplayName

#       $Has_SendAs = ($Collect_SendAs.Split("@")[0])
#          if ($User -like "*Has_SendAs*") {$User_SendAs = "yes"
#          }else{$User_SendAs = "No"}

       [pscustomobject]@{
            User =$user
            Name =$user_name.Split(',')[1..0]-join' '
            Mailbox =$Entered_email
            'Access Rights'=$Access.Trim("{","}")
            'Has Send As'=$User_SendAs
            Status ='SUCCESS'
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            User =$user
            Status ='FAILED'
            Message =$_.Exception.Message
        }
    }
}

$success,$failed=$status.Where({$_.Status -eq'SUCCESS'},'Split')
$success|selectUser,Name,Mailbox,'Access Rights','Has Send As'|Format-Table|Out-String|Write-Host-ForegroundColorGreen
$failed  |selectUser,Message|Out-String|Write-Host-ForegroundColorRed

$SoBo=Get-Mailbox$Entered_email|select @{l='SendOnBehalfOf';e={$_.GrantSendOnBehalfTo -join"`n"}}
$Sobo_Output=$SoBo-replace"@{SendOnBehalfOf=",''-replace"}",''

If ($Sobo_Output-ge1) {
Write-Host"Users With Send on Belhalf Permissions"-ForegroundColorGreen
Write-Host"--------------------------------------"-ForegroundColorGreen
Write-Host$SoBo_Output-ForegroundColorGreen
Write-Host""
}else{
Write-Host"Users With Send on Belhalf Permissions"-ForegroundColorGreen
Write-Host"--------------------------------------"-ForegroundColorGreen
Write-Host"No users found with this permission level"-ForegroundColorGreen
Write-Host""
}
Disconnect-ExchangeOnline-Confirm:$false-InformationActionIgnore-ErrorActionSilentlyContinue

Pause
```

Any advice would be appreciated at this stage, I definitely could use help with the table, I could probably figure out how to add the Send As and SoBo searches, but if anyone knows some really efficient ones please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED**

I've amended the script above, because I couldn't figure out how toadd another message.

I've taken on board the changes suggested by @TheMadTechnician, and abandoned the idea of adding SoBo to the table as the SoBo users information is saved as some weird string of names and usernames, so I've rigged it so that this information pops out on a separate table below the access level table.

I've added line 10 ($Collect_SendAs), this is a line that can pull the email addresses (username@domain.com) of all users that have **Send As** access to the mailbox, I'm looking to get this integrated into the access level table and have made a few wrong turns trying to do this (lines 22-24 are my latest failed attempts to do this).

What I would like to do with the info collected in line 10 is to strip out the @domain part, then compare it with the usernames extracted in line 11, if there match, add a "yes" to the **Send As** column for the user, and if there is no match, add a "No".

If anyone can help with this, that would be amazing.

**UPDATE**

Think I've got it:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Install-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Connect-ExchangeOnline -ShowBanner:$false
Clear-Host
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$status = [System.Collections.Generic.List[pscustomobject]]::new()

$Entered_email = Read-host "Enter a mailbox address"
$Entered_email = $Entered_email.trim()

$Collect_SendAs = Get-Mailbox $Entered_email -resultsize:unlimited | Get-RecipientPermission | where {($_.trustee -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF")} | where {($_.trustee -match "@")} | select -ExpandProperty Trustee
$Collect_users = Get-Mailbox -Identity $Entered_email -ResultSize:Unlimited | Get-MailboxPermission | ?{($_.IsInherited -eq $False) -and -not ($_.User -match "NT AUTHORITY")}
$status = foreach ($Alias in $Collect_users)

{
    try
    {
        $User = ($Alias.User.Split("@")[0]) 
        $User_name = Get-ADUser -identity $User -properties DisplayName | select -expandproperty DisplayName 
        if ($Collect_SendAs -match $User) {$User_SendAs = "yes"
        }else{$User_SendAs = "No"}
        $Access = $Alias.AccessRights

       [pscustomobject]@{
            User = $user
            Name = $user_name.Split(',')[1..0]-join' '
            Mailbox = $Entered_email
            'Access Rights' = $Access.Trim("{","}")
            'Has Send As' = $User_SendAs
            Status = 'SUCCESS'
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            User = $user
            Status = 'FAILED'
            Message = $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }
}

$success, $failed = $status.Where({$_.Status -eq 'SUCCESS'},'Split')
$success | select User, Name, Mailbox,'Access Rights','Has Send As' | Format-Table | Out-String | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green
$failed  | select User, Message | Out-String | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red

$SoBo = Get-Mailbox $Entered_email |select @{l='SendOnBehalfOf';e={$_.GrantSendOnBehalfTo -join"`n"}}
$Sobo_Output = $SoBo -replace "@{SendOnBehalfOf=",'' -replace"}",''

If ($Sobo_Output -ge 1) {
Write-Host "Users With Send on Behalf Permissions" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "--------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host $SoBo_Output -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host ""
}else{
Write-Host "Users With Send on Behalf Permissions" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "--------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "No users found with this permission level" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host ""
}
Disconnect-ExchangeOnline -Confirm:$false -InformationAction Ignore -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Pause
```

Thanks a lot to everyone who posted.

Comment: Just to clarify, unless I'm missing something, your current code is functional but you're looking for ways to improve it?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Hi there, yes it does appear to fetch the correct information, its a bit slow, but it does get there - although I haven't written anything that collects the Send As and Sobo column data yet. The biggest problem is the formatting of the results, I want it in a neat table, but 4 columns seems to be my limit before it devolves to a list.

Answer (score 1):

You are duplicating efforts a LOT with this. Line 9 would return you all the users that have access *and the access they have*, but you discard everything but the user's account name, and then later loop through those users and get their access one at a time. Here I keep that info, then use it inside the loop to reduce calls to Exchange to get perms again and again. I also changed a variable name since you re-used `$User` for different things which can be very confusing.

```
import-module activedirectory
Install-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Connect-ExchangeOnline -ShowBanner:$false
Clear-Host
$ErrorActionPreference='Stop'
$status=[System.Collections.Generic.List[pscustomobject]]::new()

$Entered_email = Read-host "Enter a mailbox address"
$Collect_users = Get-Mailbox -Identity $Entered_email -ResultSize:Unlimited|Get-MailboxPermission|?{($_.IsInherited -eq $False) -and -not ($_.User -match"NT AUTHORITY")} #|select -ExpandProperty user
$status=foreach($Alias in $Collect_users)

{
    try
    {
        $User= ($Alias.User.Split("@")[0])
        $Access=$Alias.AccessRights
        if ($Access -like "*FullAccess*") {$Access_Result="yes"
            }else{$Access_Result="No"}
        $User_name = Get-ADUser -identity $User -properties DisplayName|select -expandproperty DisplayName
 

       [pscustomobject]@{
            User = $user
            Name = $user_name
            Mailbox = $Entered_email.Split("@")[0]
            'Full Access'= $Access_Result
            Status ='SUCCESS'
        }
    }
    catch
    {

        [pscustomobject]@{
            User = $user.user
            Status ='FAILED'
            Message = $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }
}

$success,$failed=$status.Where({$_.Status -eq'SUCCESS'},'Split')
$success|Out-String|Write-Host-ForegroundColorGreen
$failed  |Out-String|Write-Host-ForegroundColorRed

Pause
```

Comment: This will fail for orgs with the same username on different domains, e.g. "Bob.Jones@acme.com" and "Bob.Jones@xyz.com" because you're relying on the "Username" being unique after you strip the domain on line 15

Comment: @MikeAnthony Sure, but I didn't change the user query, so for the OP's purpose it should work fine.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - Hi, Thanks for this, I knew there was a more efficient way, I just couldn't figure it out. I've taken your ideas on board and made some changes, such as the formatting of the output table, and I've abandoned trying to add a SoBo column, instead I've opted for a separate SoBo table. I would like to add a **Send As** column and I have figured out how to collect the information and strip it down to usernames, I just cant figure out how to compare these with the previously collected usernames and if there's a match, put a "yes" in the column and vice-versa. Any ideas? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I started making a "mailbox manager" gui last year and never got around to finishing it, but maybe there's some useful stuff you could pull from it. The last thing I was trying to add was who has access/sendas TO the selected account (bottom part of the gui), which isn't quite working...but the first part (see what accounts/sendas an account has permission for) is working.

The eventual idea was to add a "save" button in so you could check/uncheck the tickboxes as you'd like in the gui and it'd adjust the permissions.

```
#Init
$logpath = "C:\Scripts\Logs\MailboxPermissions.log"
#Create session on 365 Exchange server
if ((Get-PSSession).Computername -notmatch "outlook.office365.com"){Connect-365}#or: Connect-ExchangeOnline -ShowBanner:$false
$UPNs = Get-Mailbox -Identity * | select -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName

$AccToDatasource = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$BS1 = [System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource]::new()
$BS1.DataSource = $AccToDatasource

$AccByDatasource = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$BS2 = [System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource]::new()
$BS2.DataSource = $AccByDatasource


Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$get_permissions={
    $AccToDatasource.Clear()
    $AccByDatasource.Clear()
    $user = $ComboBox1.Text
    write-host "Checking $($user)"
    Get-EXOMailboxPermission -Identity $user | ?{$_.User -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF"} | %{
        $tablerow = New-Object psobject
        $data = @{Email="$($_.User)";Inbox=1;SendAs=0}
        $tablerow | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers $data -TypeName tablerow
        $AccToDatasource.Add($tablerow)
    }
    Get-EXORecipientPermission -Identity $user | ?{$_.Trustee -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF"} | %{
        $indx = [array]::IndexOf($AccToDatasource.Email,$_.Trustee)
        if($indx -ne -1){
            $AccToDatasource[$indx].SendAs = 1
        }else{
            $tablerow = New-Object psobject
            $data = @{Email="$($_.Trustee)";SendAs=1}
            $tablerow | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers $data -TypeName tablerow
            $AccToDatasource.Add($tablerow)
        }
    }
    $BS1.ResetBindings($true)

    <##Attempt 1
    Get-EXOMailbox -MailboxPlan "ExchangeOnlineEnterprise" -Properties UserPrincipalName | select -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName | %{
        Start-ThreadJob {
            Get-EXOMailboxPermission -Identity $using:_ -User $using:user -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        } | Wait-Job | Receive-Job | %{
                $tablerow = New-Object psobject
                $data = @{Email="$($_.Trustee)";Inbox=1;SendAs=0}
                $tablerow | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers $data -TypeName tablerow
                $AccByDatasource.Add($tablerow)
            }
    }
    $BS2.ResetBindings($true)
    #>
    
    #Attempt 2
    Get-EXOMailbox -MailboxPlan "ExchangeOnlineEnterprise" -Properties UserPrincipalName | select -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName | %{Start-ThreadJob {Get-EXOMailboxPermission -Identity $using:_ -User $using:user -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}} | Wait-Job | Receive-Job | %{
                $tablerow = New-Object psobject
                $data = @{Email="$($_.Trustee)";Inbox=1;SendAs=0}
                $tablerow | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers $data -TypeName tablerow
                $AccByDatasource.Add($tablerow)
            }
    $BS2.ResetBindings($true)
}

#Form Init
$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(600,650)
$Form.text                       = "Mailbox Manager"
$Form.TopMost                    = $false

$ComboBox1                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$ComboBox1.width                 = 370
$ComboBox1.height                = 30
$ComboBox1.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(137,25)
$ComboBox1.Font                  = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)
$ComboBox1.Items.AddRange($UPNs)
$ComboBox1.AutoCompleteSource    = "ListItems"
$ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode      = "SuggestAppend"
#$ComboBox1.add_SelectedIndexChanged({
#    if ($ComboBox1.Text.Length -gt 10){
#        get-permissions -user $ComboBox1.Text
#    }
#})

$Label1                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label1.text                     = "Select 365 User:"
$Label1.AutoSize                 = $true
$Label1.width                    = 25
$Label1.height                   = 30
$Label1.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(14,25)
$Label1.Font                     = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$Label2                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label2.text                     = "Has access to:"
$Label2.AutoSize                 = $true
$Label2.width                    = 25
$Label2.height                   = 30
$Label2.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(14,55)
$Label2.Font                     = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$Label3                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label3.text                     = "Accessible by:"
$Label3.AutoSize                 = $true
$Label3.width                    = 25
$Label3.height                   = 30
$Label3.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(14,358)
$Label3.Font                     = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$DataGridView1                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$DataGridView1.text              = "Emails"
$DataGridView1.width             = 560
$DataGridView1.height            = 250
$DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = $false
$DataGridView1.Columns.Add((new-object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn -Property @{"Name"="Email"})) | Out-Null
$DataGridView1.Columns['Email'].DataPropertyName = "Email"
$DataGridView1.Columns.Add((new-object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn -Property @{"Name"="Inbox"})) | Out-Null
$DataGridView1.Columns['Inbox'].DataPropertyName = "Inbox"
$DataGridView1.Columns.Add((new-object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn -Property @{"Name"="SendAs"})) | Out-Null
$DataGridView1.Columns['SendAs'].DataPropertyName = "SendAs"
$DataGridView1.Columns.Add((new-object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn -Property @{"Name"="Start"})) | Out-Null
$DataGridView1.Columns['Start'].DataPropertyName = "Start"
$DataGridView1.Columns.Add((new-object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn -Property @{"Name"="End"})) | Out-Null
$DataGridView1.Columns['End'].DataPropertyName = "End"
$DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = $true
$DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = 10
$DataGridView1.DataSource = $BS1
$DataGridView1.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(11,82)
$DataGridView1.BackColor         = [System.Drawing.ColorTranslator]::FromHtml("#e0dede")
$DataGridView1.add_DataError({write-host "hit error"})


$DataGridView2                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$DataGridView2.width             = 560
$DataGridView2.height            = 250
$DataGridView2.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(9,383)
$DataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = $false
$DataGridView2.Columns.Add((new-object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn -Property @{"Name"="Email"})) | Out-Null
$DataGridView2.Columns['Email'].DataPropertyName = "Email"
$DataGridView2.Columns.Add((new-object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn -Property @{"Name"="Inbox"})) | Out-Null
$DataGridView2.Columns['Inbox'].DataPropertyName = "Inbox"
$DataGridView2.Columns.Add((new-object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn -Property @{"Name"="SendAs"})) | Out-Null
$DataGridView2.Columns['SendAs'].DataPropertyName = "SendAs"
$DataGridView2.Columns.Add((new-object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn -Property @{"Name"="Start"})) | Out-Null
$DataGridView2.Columns['Start'].DataPropertyName = "Start"
$DataGridView2.Columns.Add((new-object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn -Property @{"Name"="End"})) | Out-Null
$DataGridView2.Columns['End'].DataPropertyName = "End"
$DataGridView2.ColumnHeadersVisible = $true
$DataGridView2.AutoSizeColumnsMode = 10
$DataGridView2.DataSource = $BS2
$DataGridView2.BackColor         = [System.Drawing.ColorTranslator]::FromHtml("#e0dede")

$loadButton                      = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$loadButton.text                 = "Load"
$loadButton.width                = 60
$loadButton.height               = 30
$loadButton.location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(509,25)
$loadButton.Font                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)
$loadButton.Add_Click($get_permissions)

$saveButton                      = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$saveButton.text                 = "Save"
$saveButton.width                = 60
$saveButton.height               = 30
$saveButton.location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(509,341)
$saveButton.Font                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($Label1,$Label2,$Label3,$ComboBox1,$DataGridView1,$DataGridView2,$saveButton, $loadButton))

[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: This is phenomenal! I couldn't get it to work on my organisation's estate, the GUI did open, but there was a sea of red in ISE and the GUI didn't respond. It's probably down to version or dependency issues but it's still an amazing piece of work and I hope to someday understand it better.

Comment: Line 4 (connect-365) is a custom function call, replace it with the commented out part on the same line to connect normally.